# calling jQuery Mobile inside an iframe

Tags: jquery, iframe

Below is the theme changing function and it's working fine.

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<!--<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/theme.css">-->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.0/theme-classic/theme-classic.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $( document ).on( "pagecreate", function() {
        $( "#theme-selector input" ).on( "change", function( event ) {
            var themeClass = $( "#theme-selector input:checked" ).attr( "id" );

            $( "#testpage" ).removeClass( "ui-page-theme-a ui-page-theme-b ui-page-theme-c ui-page-theme-d ui-page-theme-e" ).addClass( "ui-page-theme-" + themeClass );
        });
    });
</script>   
</head>
<body>    
<div data-role="page" id="testpage">

<div data-role="header">
<h1>Untitled App</h1>
</div>

<div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
<form class="ui-mini">
  <div class="ui-field-contain" id="theme-selector">
      <fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal">
          <legend>Theme:</legend>
          <label for="a">A</label>
          <input type="radio" name="theme" id="a" checked>
          <label for="b">B</label>
          <input type="radio" name="theme" id="b">
          <label for="c">C</label>
          <input type="radio" name="theme" id="c">
          <label for="d">D</label>
          <input type="radio" name="theme" id="d">
          <label for="e">E</label>
          <input type="radio" name="theme" id="e">
      </fieldset>
  </div>
</form>

</div>

<div data-role="footer">
<h1>Footer Text</h1>
</div>

</div> 
</body>
</html>
```

I've created another page and use iframe to load the page just now. I also moved the function and buttons over this page.

loader.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script>
    $( document ).on( "pagecreate", function() {
        $( "#theme-selector input" ).on( "change", function( event ) {
            var themeClass = $( "#theme-selector input:checked" ).attr( "id" );

            $( "#testpage" ).removeClass( "ui-page-theme-a ui-page-theme-b ui-page-theme-c ui-page-theme-d ui-page-theme-e" ).addClass( "ui-page-theme-" + themeClass );
        });
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div align="center">
<form class="ui-mini">
<div class="ui-field-contain" id="theme-selector">
    <fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal">
        <legend>Theme:</legend>
        <label for="a">A</label>
        <input type="radio" name="theme" id="a" checked>
        <label for="b">B</label>
        <input type="radio" name="theme" id="b">
        <label for="c">C</label>
        <input type="radio" name="theme" id="c">
        <label for="d">D</label>
        <input type="radio" name="theme" id="d">
        <label for="e">E</label>
        <input type="radio" name="theme" id="e">
    </fieldset>
</div>
</form>
<iframe src="index.html" id="resultFrame" seamless width="320" height="568" style="border:1px solid #999;"></iframe> 
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

The form not working anymore. Is there any way to let the function call the id that is inside an iframe?

Comment: This needs to be pared down to a simpler example of what's not working. If you actually take the time to do that you'll probably notice what's wrong with your code.

Comment: Hi Jonathan, i tried moved the function inside the iframe and calling the parent selector input, but not working either. I tried alot method but still no clue :(